Tuya application mobile certificate ios Group ID already taken
I'm creating an application with Tuya, i am to the step: 03 build app
I'm creating IOS certificates, i created App ID, but for the Group ID, i removed a last one and creating another one i got the message: "An App ID with Identifier ‘com.xxx.xxx’ is not available. Please enter a different string.".
Tuya documentation say: "The registered Identifier must be the App ID prefixed with group and the App ID must be the one created in the previous step. For example, if the App ID created in the previous step is com.example.app, the Group ID Identifier must be group.com.example.app.".
So i cannot have a Group ID that match the App Id.

I've contacted Apple to get back the Group ID available but this take time and maybe the answer will be no.
I've contacted Tuya, they tell me to create a new application.

The solutions that i have:

Wait for Apple response.
Create a new application on Tuya but this is a lot of work.
Change the application name to have new bundle id on Tuya but i don't want to change the application name.

I was wondering if there is another way to fix this ?

The error is simple and the Group ID could be usef from another compagny, i find it hard to believe that having a Group ID already taken could block an entire release. That would be poorly designed.
Maybe i can copy paste my Tuya application and juste change the bundles IDS but i didn't find it.

Have a nice day
